# How can I create a transaction in Perl's Finance::QIF?

Tags: perl, quicken, qif

I am trying to create a transaction in a QIF file in Perl.  I thought that using [Finance::QIF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Finance-QIF) would let me create a simple transaction (example: spending $20 at Best Buy), but I'm not seeing a way to do this.

Does someone have an example or is there a difference module that I should be using to create a transaction?

Thanks!

--Noah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the documentation doesn't have any examples of writing a record, the [tests](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MMCGILLIS/Finance-QIF-3.00/t/Finance-QIF.t) do.  I modified this from the test file:

```
  my $out = Finance::QIF->new( file => ">" . $somefile, );
  my $record = {
      header      => "Type:Bank",
      date        => "8/26/09",
      payee       => "Best Buy",
      memo        => "",
      transaction => "-20.00",
      address     => "",
      category    => "Entertainment",
  };
  $out->header( $record->{header} );
  $out->write($record);
  $out->close;
```

Comment: Need a comma after "8/26/09"..

Besides that it works great!!